# Encrypting web.config with RSA

Tags: asp.net, encryption, web-config

When I use aspnet_regiis to encrypt a web.config, the initial line says

```
configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"
```

and later down it says

```
<EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
```

and further after that it says

```
<EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
      <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
```

I am confused why the tripledes line is in there when the provider is the RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the sequence of events that used to encrypt the method **RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider** in **webconfig**

```
 <appSettings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
<EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
  <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
  <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
      <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <KeyName>XXXXXX</KeyName>
      </KeyInfo>
      <CipherData>
        <CipherValue>GW5cBFyCHZxAmSTGf+eKfIQmi7Vy450CGKEnMk8nJBW+3w0R4QZAEyneaZ0=</CipherValue>
      </CipherData>
    </EncryptedKey>
  </KeyInfo>
  <CipherData>
    <CipherValue>vH3V+KnNRAc9ps+AhzrrFf2HABiqI/dlnYCCDE+wxoUZ4CoVReswbyTKU4ZybcuxmUwV2z5kUNaAQ8Rmei3IsN7VRx7pVXjDtOT4osA0Jc</CipherValue>
  </CipherData>
</EncryptedData>
```

help yourself with this: [ete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.rsaprotectedconfigurationprovider.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a key first to use?

Here is an example how to do it, scroll down to web farm scenarios: [msdn microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998283.aspx)